# Importing CUnit sources

Tags: c, unit-testing, configure, cunit

i'm having a problem to use Unit test in C, i've tried to install CUnit in my computer and after include the lib.

i've followed steeps to install the CUnit:

```
1 - download the sources
2 - configure it using "./configure --prefix='/lib' "
3 - make (only make)
4 - sudo make install
```

and this is my test source file, it's not making tests, but i can't compile this, i got this error before "CUnit.h: No such file or directory":

```
#include "CUnit.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


    print("Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know, how can i install CUnit to use in my test source files!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

HAHA, i got this!

i just run configure without parameters, like that:

```
"./configure"
```

Comment: If you've solved your own question, post your answer as a standalone answer and select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [code example](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/example.html) you should use something like this :

```
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>
```

because every CUnit includes are located in a CUnit subdirectory (in general in `/usr/local/include/CUnit`)

Comment: I got the same error: "fatal error: Cunit/CUnit.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: @guisantogui : how do you compile your file, with which options ?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `-I/lib/include` flag to include header files installed in `/lib/include/CUnit` and `-lcunit -L/lib/CUnit/lib` for linking with the installed libraries?

`gcc test_file_source.c -I/lib/include -lcunit -L/lib/CUnit/lib -o testing`